# Finding duplicate records with LINQ with matching on multiple columns?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to write a query to find all potential duplicate records for a user. A duplicate is defined as any of the following:

- (Last Name OR First Name) + (Email OR Phone) match
- Record A ExternalID must be null + Record B ExternalID must not be null

I have data coming from two separate systems, from system B the externalID on my table will be populated with a GUID, from system A the externalID will be null. I'm only concerned with finding duplicates between the two systems, not duplicates within each system.

The query i have thus far:

```
 Dim duplicates = db.People.Where(Function(c) c.CID = CID And c.DeleteFlag = False). _
        Where(Function(p) p.EmailAddress <> Nothing And p.ExternalID <> Nothing) _
       .GroupBy(Function(i) New With {i.EmailAddress, i.LastName, i.FirstName}) _
       .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).[Select](Function(g) g.Key)
```

Issues I am having:

- ExternalID matching logic does not work
- Matching only records where the emailaddress, lastname, and firstname all match exactly
- Using an anonymous type in the group, i'm unable to pull out the records unique ID. If i add the PK into the grouping I wont get any results.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `<>` or `=` to compare with [`Nothing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/0x9tb07z.aspx), you 'll always get `False`(similar as in sql). `Nothing` isn't equal or unequal to anything else. Instead use `IsNot` or `Is Nothing`. Also use [`AndAlso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead of `And` (and `OrElse` instead of `Or`).

In VB.NET (as opposed to C#) you also have to specify the key-columns  which are used for  `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of the anonymous type.

```
Dim duplicates = db.People.Where(Function(c) c.CID = CID And c.DeleteFlag = False). 
       Where(Function(p) p.EmailAddress IsNot Nothing AndAlso p.ExternalID IsNot Nothing).
       GroupBy(Function(i) New With {Key i.EmailAddress, Key i.LastName, Key i.FirstName}).
       Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).
       Select(Function(g) g.Key)
```

Comment: Take a look at my comment above regarding the `GroupBy` query (I confirmed yesterday that your version doesn't work).

Comment: In any case, my whole advice was `Key .randomName = i.EmailAddress` what is not required here, so I will better delete my comment above. Although this (the `.randomName =` part) is required when doing this with the columns of a `DataTable` to avoid the error "Anonymous type member name can be inferred only..." (what happens in both C# & VB.NET).

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for the feedback. Still have issues with ExternalID as this query excludes any Nothing records for external ID. I'm trying to find matches where 1 record has an external id, and 1 record does not have an external ID. If both records have an external ID, or neither records have one it is not a valid result. I also can not figure out how to have 1 query perform all the match criteria (right now have multiple query and then concatenate them)